# IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected when using Seaborn

Tags: python, scipy, seaborn

I'm using Seaborn `kdeplot` to plot cumulative distributions of my data. Each dataframe is about 1.5 million rows long. I'm concatenating them into one big dataframe.

When I try to plot them, I get the following warning:

```
IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be underestimated 
warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
/home/my_computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py:385
```

When I concatenate only three dataframes it works and the plots show. But then I concatenate 10 I get the warning.

Here's a sample of my call to kdeplot:

```
sns.kdeplot(df_list[i][header], cumulative=True, legend=False, ax=ax1)
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Does sampling the dataframe to use fewer rows work?